# Declare and initialize an object in JSP from Model

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I have passed a model which is a list of Objects in my JSP.

```
model.addAttribute("videosList", videosList);
```

Now I want to access declare an object by getting first element of this list.
I tried

```
<% MyVideo firstVideo = ${videosList[0]} %>
```

But it is giving me error delete this token '$'

What is the possible way to assign firstVideo from the list videosList without using jstl foreach loop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing scriptlets and spring expression language by using it together.

You can retrieve the first element of the list like below.

```
<c:set var="firstVideo" value="${videosList[0]}"/>
```

Refer [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html)

Comment: Thanks @Alien, I am new to jsp and was looking something like that